# Extracting the Charset Code of the Contents Area of Incoming Emails

Tags: java, regex, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I'm creating an email client program with JavaMail.

When an email is received, I want to take over the character code of the sender.

I have successfully obtained all the header parts of the emails and I can saved them to the database.

Is there a method to extract only the charset code that is attached the contents area (ie. charset="iso-2022-jp") of incoming emails. I am using regular expression in Java, but is there a different method to achieve this.

Below is the Pattern that I have written but is unsuccessful in extracting the code :

```
Pattern.compile("text/(plain|html);\\s*(charset(\\s*)=(\\s*\")*)(.+?)(\")");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in regex you can try with

```
Pattern.compile("text/(?:plain|html);\\s*charset\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"");
```

It should store encoding part in group 1 so you can use this pattern like

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(yourData);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
else
    System.out.println("no encoding informations");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [javax.mail.internet.ContentType(Sting)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/ContentType.html#ContentType%28java.lang.String%29) constructor and to parse the content type then call [getParameter("charset")](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/ContentType.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to fetch the charset value.